# IllegalArgumentException in Random

Tags: java, android

Here is my exception `caused by: java.lang.illegalargumentexception: at java.util.random.nextint (random.java:388).`
I have an application in the play market, and after I added Gson to the application, failures began to arrive, but rare 5 in a week.
I have installed ProGuard, all settings gson he indicated.
Tested on a large number of devices, and never I have there was no exception. I have a list in which I record JSON and then this list pass Random.nextInt.
I have read in the documentation to random that illegalargumentexception crashes when passing the method of negative value, so when I read the data is in the list of nothing is recorded. If has been an error in the gson I got to the exception in gson, I correctly understand?
I think the main problem is reading JSON. My JSON file has an array of 500 objects. questionsFromJson.size() should never be 0. I need to solve the problem why GSON returns 0 items, but should 500
I can’t recreate this error for myself, I don’t know how to fix it.

```
questionsFromJson = getQuestionsFromJson(R.raw.ru, context);

for (int i = 0; i < QUESTIONS_SIZE; i++){
        int index = random.nextInt(questionsFromJson.size());
        int imageId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(questionsFromJson.get(index).getImage().replace(".png", "") , "drawable", packageName);
        questionsFromJson.get(index).setImageId(imageId);
        questions.add(questionsFromJson.remove(index));
    }

private ArrayList<Question> getQuestionsFromJson(int id, Context context){
    ArrayList<Question> result;
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    Type dtoListType = new TypeToken<List<Question>>(){}.getType();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(context.getResources().openRawResource(id));
    result = gson.fromJson(reader, dtoListType);
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`nextInt()` throws the exception for values `<= 0`, not just negative.

Your `for` loop does not consider the size of the `questionsFromJson` collection and `questionsFromJson.size()` might become `0`.

Consider changing e.g. the `i < QUESTIONS_SIZE` condition to e.g. `i < QUESTIONS_SIZE && questionsFromJson.size() > 0`.

Comment: Yes it is. My json file has an array of 500 objects. `questionsFromJson.size()` should never be 0. I need to solve the problem why GSON returns 0 items, but should 500.